# Replace string on databind in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace, translation

I'm trying to create a multi-lingual app that fetches the translations via an initial JSON fetch, based on the user's choice.

The translations are working fine, however I need to be able to replace a string with a computed number. For example: "Tim is X% bigger than Tom.", in Spanish it might be something like "Tim es X% más alto que Tom". I need to replace X with a computed number.

Is there an Angular filter that can do this? Something akin to

```
{{ translation.PhraseOne | replaceXWithY }}
```

If not, what would be the simplest way of achieving this? I don't really want to be having a translation file with partial strings.

Cheers!

Comment: Angular Translate's variable replacement might be of interest https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement ... also there is more thorough pluralization support if you need - https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating your own custom filter.

```
angular.module('yourCustomFilter', [])
.filter('replaceXwithY', function() {
    return function(input, placeHolder,desiredValue){
        return input.replace(placeHolder,desiredValue);
    };
})
```

And in your markup:
    {{translation.PhraseOne | replaceXwithY: X:Y}}